# Prove $ \lim_\limits{n \to\infty}{(1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + \frac{1}{n!})} = e $

Tags: limits

Use that $ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n} = e $ to show that $ \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + \frac{1}{n!}\right)} = e $

I can't figure this one out. Can I get some help in solving this?

Comment: The constant, Euler's number

Comment: use the taylor series for $e^x$, x=1, or use binomial thereom to expand.